# How can I write a base64 to file in jaseci

Tags: jaseci

Yeah, how do I confuse about how to save files to jaseci files system? I would love amazing documentation or something to build on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per version 1.3.5.16 of Jaseci, the standard library has added `file.load_to_b64(fn: str)` which will load a binary file and return a base64 string and `file.dump_from_b64(fn: str, b64: str)` which will store a binary file after converting its second parameter from base64 to the relevant bits.

This example code should produce a viewable gif from base64 and also load it back and report the same base64.

```
global gif = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";

walker bin_load_save {
    file.dump_from_b64("file.gif", global.gif);
    s=file.load_to_b64("file.gif");
    report s;
}
```